# from excel to sql server

Tags: .net, sql-server, excel

I have some excel files that contains some information I need to convert it to a sql server database. The problem I face is that these information are not structures as my database model so I need to do some modifications.I am using .net and I'm thinking to use **Open XML SDK** to parse the excel files, is this a good choice or there is better ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why not use an SSIS package if available?

http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1393/import-excel-unicode-data-with-sql-server-integration-services/

You can then execute the SSIS package recursively, or...

if you need to do it just one time, I'd take a look at the SSMS import / export wizard... not sure if it does excel, but I know it does .csvs, which you can use excel to convert your spreadsheets to.  Not very fun if you need to do this a bunch of times though, but quicker than any other approach in regards to your time.

Answer (score 0):

Your choices are

1. [Microsoft Excel Automation Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wss56bz7%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)
2. Open XML SDK
3. [SharePoint Excel automation services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff640648%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

The benefit of **1** is that it has a less learning curve , more samples on the net etc. But it needs Excel to be installed on the machine and is very resource intensive. Don't expect 100 simultaneous conversions easily.

The benefit of **2** is that its free and consumes very little system resources but is harder to master. If you need to do this automated on a server 2) makes sense

**3** option is also good if you need it on a server box but you need a sharepoint installation